# Numpy: select only one instance of a recurring value in a numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I have a numpy array of of the kind:

```
a=
array([[ 253.59,  309.96,    5.02, -180.  ,  -69.36, -169.  ],
       [ 253.59,  309.96,    5.02, -178.15,  -66.1 , -169.  ],
       [ 253.59,  309.96,    5.02, -178.15,  -66.1 , -169.  ],
       [ 253.59,  309.96,    5.02, -177.17,  -60.  , -166.65],
       [ 253.59,  309.96,    5.02, -176.85,  -60.  , -166.65],
       [ 255.82,  316.87,   31.31, -176.85,  -58.78, -166.65],
       [ 255.82,  316.87,   31.31, -162.37,  -58.78, -165.31],
       [ 255.82,  316.87,   31.31, -160.91,  -58.78, -165.31],
       [ 255.82,  316.87,   31.31, -160.26,  -58.78, -153.87],
       [ 255.82,  316.87,   31.31, -157.92,  -56.88, -153.87],
       [ 266.74,  322.35,   32.23, -157.92,  -56.88, -150.  ],
       [ 266.74,  322.35,   32.23, -157.14,  -56.88, -150.  ],
       [ 266.74,  322.35,   32.23, -156.24,  -56.88, -137.  ],
       [ 266.74,  322.35,   32.23, -150.  ,  -53.86, -137.  ],
       [ 266.74,  322.35,   32.24, -148.81,  -53.86, -134.69]])
```

As you can see cols 1,2,3 are identical but cols 4,5,6 arent always identical. I want to be able to select at least one instance of each row. The selection can be random.
For example, the desired output is

```
b=
array([[ 253.59,  309.96,    5.02, -177.17,  -60.  , -166.65],...
 [255.82,  316.87,   31.31, -162.37,  -58.78, -165.31],...
 [ 266.74,  322.35,   32.23, -156.24,  -56.88, -137.  ]])
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried np.unique but that doesn't appear to work in this case. I have also tried selecting based on the calculating the difference between a[0]-a[1], but this is as far as I got and I am not sure that is the right way to do it.

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i-1):
        b=a[i]-a[j]
        print(b)
```

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Best,
Pranav

Comment: It seems `b = np.unique(a, axis=0)` should fit your needs.

Comment: hi Demi, I have tried that and it returns all instances. It appears that I cannot restrict its "match" function to only the desired cols.